# SQL - Created Database Location

Tags: c#, mysql

Where is the Database file location that I created in MySQL - Command Line Client. I searched a lot and it says it was located in. `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data"`. But the Data folder is not existing.

Example.

```
CREATE DATABASE Sample;
use Sample;
```

Where will I be able to find the database file for Sample?

Comment: Are you using MSSQL Server?

Comment: Run `select @@datadir`

Comment: @stuartd No need to be snarky - someone just edited the tags as well...

Comment: No worries @stuartd :)

Comment: Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%datadir"
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @JetSeighart For future reference it's helpful for the person asking the question to mark the answer as correct (using the check mark) if it helped them.